# Get mobile device type in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, device

I want to know the Mobile Device (like iPhone X) in unity.

[https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NroYU.png)

I got to know whether a device running on unity is iPhone X by this code...

```
if ( SystemInfo.deviceModel == “iPhone10,3”
|| SystemInfo.deviceModel == “iPhone10,6”)
```

But, how can I know whether a device is Samsung Galaxy S9 or LG V30?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceModel.html should work for Andorid and other OS too

Comment: thanks! That page really helps... but I eager to know is that "manufacturer model" format (e.g. "LGE Nexus 5" or "SAMSUNG-SM-G900A")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same function.

**SystemInfo.deviceModel**

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceModel.html

Unity can also recognize your OS (Operative System). So you can recognize when is an Android Device, iOs Device, or windows platform, even if you are running on your Unity Editor.

If you are working on VR, you can also discern devices with XR, devices like Oculus, HTC, Cardboard, etc.

Comment: I really appreciate it. Then if I want to know whether the device is Galaxy S8, SystemInfo.deviceModel == “???”

Comment: From the same link "Android device names are often in "manufacturer model" format (e.g. "LGE Nexus 5" or "SAMSUNG-SM-G900A")." Also I got a Galaxy S8 if it is your main preocupation, I can try to extract the name ^^

Comment: Also I found that repo that maybe can help you, cause this repo has it's own database filled with "manufacturer model" name! https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames

Comment: With iOS, you can get the device you are dealing with, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.DeviceGeneration.html with Android, because of the large range of devices, this would be ridiculously large. You'd have to know how it is described by the OS as mentioned above.

Comment: But maybe knowing why you need to know whether one or the other could help provide a better answer. I mean do you need to know a specific device or more likely a specific hardware?

Comment: Yep @Everts, the best approach should be choose the specs from hardware instead of the model: how much RAM, CPU, etc But imagine, for example, that he wants to know the model to choose the specific logo of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Systeminfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo.html) class to figure out capabilities of the underlying platform and hardware.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SystemInfoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Text info;
    string infoString = "";
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       infoString += "Battery Level: " + SystemInfo.batteryLevel + "\n";
       infoString += "Battery Status: " + SystemInfo.batteryStatus + "\n";
       infoString += "Device Model: " + SystemInfo.deviceModel + "\n";
       infoString += "Device Name: " + SystemInfo.deviceName + "\n";
       infoString += "Device Type: " + SystemInfo.deviceType + "\n";
       infoString += "Device Unique Identifier: " + SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier + "\n";
       infoString += "Operating System: " + SystemInfo.operatingSystem + "\n";
       infoString += "Processor Type: " + SystemInfo.processorType + "\n";
       infoString += "Memory Size: " + SystemInfo.systemMemorySize + "\n";
       infoString += "Acceleromer Support: " + SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer + "\n";
       infoString += "Gyroscope Support: " + SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope + "\n";
       infoString += "Vibration Support: " + SystemInfo.supportsVibration + "\n";
       info.text = infoString;

       // For more: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo.html
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

For more: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo.html